# How to automatically send screenshot to someone on Telegram

Tags: command-line, bash, clipboard, screenshot, telegram

I want to send screenshots automatically to someone as soon as I capture my screen. I can use [telegram-cli](https://github.com/vysheng/tg) to send the screenshot but I can't figure out that how can I chose the photo on my clipboard to send. So what will be the solution, writing a bash script to send file from clipboard or sending latest picture from the screenshot directory. How can I achive that?

How can I write a bash script that looks for the screenshot folder and if a new file got created then it will send it.

or It will look to my clipboard so when I take a screenshot it sends the photo on my clipboard.

Thanks.